# Object reassignment inside functions in R

Tags: r

Slightly embarrassed to ask such a simple question but I've wasted an hour now and figure its a 30 second solution. The problem is how to edit an existing object that is provided as an input to a function. I've also played with the super-assignment `<<-` without success.

The example function uses 2 inputs (one for an object and one for its name). I just need a form of this that removes the need for the 'n' input.

```
m <- c(2,5,3,7,1,3,9,3,5)
dim(m) <- c(3,3)
m

f <- function(x, n) { # where 'n' is the object name of 'x'
  x[1,] <- c(1,2,3)
  assign(n, x, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}

f(m, 'm')
m
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This can be dangerous, and goes against the grain of functional programming. What's wrong with writing `x <- somefun(x)`?

Comment: I only want a generic function that will edit the values of an existing object. Is that dangerous?  I've tried other approaches but they fail because the function cannot identify global object 'x'..

Comment: For instance these also fail:

Comment: `f1 <- function(x) x[1,] <<- c(1,2,3); f1(m)`

Comment: What would you want to see if you tried, for example, `f(2)`.

Comment: `f2 <- function(x) assign(x[1,], c(1,2,3), envir = .GlobalEnv); f2(m)`

Comment: @seancarmody The function would only receive a specific dimension matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to provide the name as an extra argument; `substitute` will get that for you. To do things in the scope of the calling function you use `eval` with `parent.frame`.

```
f <- function(x) {
  eval(substitute( x[1,] <- c(1,2,3) ), parent.frame())
}
```

Then,

```
m <- c(2,5,3,7,1,3,9,3,5)
> dim(m) <- c(3,3)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    2    7    9
[2,]    5    1    3
[3,]    3    3    5
> f(m)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    5    1    3
[3,]    3    3    5
```

That said, modifying the caller's environment is generally a bad idea and it will usually lead to less confusing/fragile code if you just return the value and re-assign it to `m` instead. This is generally preferable.:

```
f <- function (x) {
    x[1,] <- c(1,2,3)
    x
}

m <- f(m)
```

However, I have occasionally found `eval` shenanigans to come in handy when I really needed to change an array in place and avoid an array copy.

Answer (score 5):

OK solved. Thanks @Andrie, sorry I misunderstood your reply.

Rookie error :(

```
f <- function(x) {
  x[1,] <- c(1,2,3)
  return(x)
}

m <- f(m)
m
```

Comment: You should click the checkmark to indicate this is a satisfactory solution.

Answer (score 2):

I am probably missing the point of why you want to do this, but this will do exactly what you want, I think:

```
m[1,] = c(1,2,3)
```

The value of m has been changed in the global environment.

I'm just guessing here, but often folks who are writing functions to take the "names" of objects find that R lists can be useful.  If you find yourself wanting to manipulate variables based on names, consider using R lists instead.  Remember that every member of a list can have a different data type if necessary.

Comment: Normally I'd agree, but I was trying to develop a complex function. My error was to try and apply a 'f(x)' process to a situation demanding 'x <- f(x)'